# 404 error with Skyscanner rapid api to get flight infos

Tags: postman, httprequest, skyscanner, rapidapi

I can not get response from skyscanner api. Did I write something wrong?

[https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/referral/v1.0/UK/GBP/en-GB/EDI/LHR/2021-05-26/2021-05-26?shortapikey=ra66933236979928&apiKey={shortapikey}](https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/referral/v1.0/UK/GBP/en-GB/EDI/LHR/2021-05-26/2021-05-26?shortapikey=ra66933236979928&apiKey=%7Bshortapikey%7D)

[image]

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Could be that the API is not active anymore?

Comment: I am of the same opinion too.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint you're trying to access doesn't exist. That's why it's returning 404.

Visit the homepage of [Skyscanner API](https://rapidapi.com/skyscanner/api/skyscanner-flight-search/) on RapidAPI Hub and take a look at the different endpoints it supports.

I believe you want an endpoint that return fligh information. Check out the endpoints available in the `Browse Flight Prices` category and pick a best one for you according to your needs.

[image]